# JCEF : CefApp dispose and restart

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I am using JCEF (Java Chromium enabled framework) in my application.

The scenario is When user clicks on "Launch" button i have to launch the browser window and when he closes the window i have to exit the browser and clean up.

The code is:

```
   addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    try {
                        CefApp.getInstance().dispose();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
                    } finally {
                        dispose();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Calling the `dispose()` makes the cefApp state to TERMINATED. So when user clicks on Launch again i try to initilize cefApp it says

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CefApp was terminated
```

because the `CefApp.getInstance()` throws this error if state is TERMINATED.

What is the way to dispose and restart CefApp overcoming this?

Comment: You can only initialize once per process. JCEF questions are best asked on https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=17

Comment: I have a [similar question posted on the JCEF forum](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=17615&sid=b9f26be6db133cffa739f35c6f41fabb)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse the `CefApp` instance, you cannot call `dispose()` on it. Rather, you need to call `dispose()` on the `CefClient` instance before removing any browser UI components from their containers. If you dispose the client after removing the UI component (which happens as part of `Window.dispose()`, it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

how about, finding a way of not close JCEF, but instead just Set.Visible(false)